# Как я могу остановить animate в hover?

Tags: jquery

```js
bArrow[0].hover(function () {
  arrow[0].animate({backgroundColor: '#5435B9'})
},
  function () {
    arrow[0].stop(true, true)
   
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Я не понимаю как мне остановить ховер эффект чтобы bgc перестал работать?
Сейчас он работает с помощью плагина.

Answer (score 0):

При использовании анимации на ховере я рекомендую использовать css анимацию, а не js. Вот пример:

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
   background-color: #6d6d6d;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
div:hover {
  background:#5435B9;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Если вы все же хотите использовать JQuery анимацию, то вам надо подключить еще и [JQuery color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color). Т.к. стандартная функция animate в JQuery не может управлять свойством background-color.